# Postgres UTC timestamps?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I want a UTC timestamp "created" field in several tables.

`ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),` gives me the local-time with time zone:

```
foo=# select ts from messages;
              ts               
-------------------------------
 2017-05-26 11:54:07.532796+01
 2017-05-26 11:54:08.536241+01
 2017-05-26 11:54:09.538119+01
 2017-05-26 11:54:10.541089+01
 2017-05-26 11:54:11.543262+01
```

`ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),` gives me local time without timezone information (dangerous):

```
foo=# select ts from messages;
             ts             
----------------------------
 2017-05-26 11:56:00.134596
 2017-05-26 11:56:01.13798
 2017-05-26 11:56:02.140586
 2017-05-26 11:56:03.143076
 2017-05-26 11:56:04.14565
```

What field definition will give me the following, when the code is run on a server in a non-UTC time zone (e.g. BST, British Summer Time):

```
foo=# select ts from messages;
             ts             
----------------------------
 2017-05-26 10:56:00.134596+00
 2017-05-26 10:56:01.13798+00
 2017-05-26 10:56:02.140586+00
 2017-05-26 10:56:03.143076+00
 2017-05-26 10:56:04.14565+00
```

even:

```
foo=# select ts from messages;
             ts             
----------------------------
 2017-05-26 10:56:00.134596
 2017-05-26 10:56:01.13798
 2017-05-26 10:56:02.140586
 2017-05-26 10:56:03.143076
 2017-05-26 10:56:04.14565
```

would be fine, if nothing else is possible (note: times are 10am UTC, not 11am BST in both examples above).

Comment: timestamptz will do. your client time zone will operate the time, which value will be converted to UTC and saved to server. postgres keeps all timestaptz in UTC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

timestamp with time zone is your choice:

```
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-05-26 11:04:19.240294+00
(1 row)

t=# set timezone to 'EET';
SET
t=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-05-26 14:04:45.749123+03
(1 row)
```

but if you insert into select now() it will save time at UTC which you can check:

```
t=# select now() at time zone 'utc';
          timezone
----------------------------
 2017-05-26 11:05:01.045544
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
>   are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
>   configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

Comment: Thanks once more.  I hadn't understood that Postgres was giving the client a (client-)localised time, rather than storing a localised time.